# Change linked table source in Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Appreciate any help I can get on this one.

I am using a script to automatically push content from a spreadsheet to a document as a sort of super mail merge. Changing the text in the document is no problem, but getting the tables in the document to behave has proved more difficult.

Every table in the document is linked to the spreadsheet. What I'm trying to do, with limited luck, is any of the following:

- Change the source table on the document from one spreadsheet to another, then update all the values.
- Update all the source tables on the document, then unlink from the source.
- Directly copy ranges from a spreadsheet to a document.

I haven't had any luck so far. The code below is where I'm up to. the `getLinkUrl()` attribute returns null for every table found in the document. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
function updateTables(documentID,spreadsheetID){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

//Check if input was passed
  if(documentID === undefined){
    var documentURL = ui.prompt('Table Update Module','Please enter the url of the document you wish to update tables on.', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
//Check for cancel
    if(documentURL.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK){ 
      documentID = getIdFromUrl(documentURL.getResponseText());
    }else{
      Logger.log('Exit when asked for document URL.');
      return;}
  }
  Logger.log('Replacement document ID: ' + documentID);

//Check if input was passed
  if(spreadsheetID === undefined){
    var spreadsheetURL = ui.prompt('Table Update Module','Please enter the url of the spreadsheet you wish to get the tables from.', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
//Check for cancel
    if(spreadsheetURL.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK){ 
      spreadsheetID = getIdFromUrl(spreadsheetURL.getResponseText());
    }else{
      Logger.log('Exit when asked for spreadsheet URL.');
      return;}
  }
  Logger.log('Replacement spreadsheet ID: ' + spreadsheetID);

//Get tables
  var documentTables = DocumentApp.openById(documentID).getBody().getTables();

//Loop through tables
  for(var i = 0; i < documentTables.length; ++i){
    Logger.log('Table URL: ' + documentTables[i].getLinkUrl());
  }  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement null checker?

Comment: @jess, thank you for the suggestion, but checking for null values is not the problem. Using `getLinkUrl()` for tables does not return the linked URL of the table, it returns any hyperlinks which have been assigned to that table.

Answer (score -2):

Setting a link URL to the table does not mean any automatic data updates. This is only a hyperlink to some other resource, nothing more. If you had not set the link explicitly before, using `Table.setLinkUrl()` method, you will get **null** from every call of `Table.getLinkUrl()`.

Below is a sample code for the document having at least 1 table, where the method returns a string value, not **null**.

```
function getLinkUrl() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var tables = doc.getBody().getTables();
  tables[0].setLinkUrl('https://stackoverflow.com');
  Logger.log(tables[0].getLinkUrl());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the `getLinkUrl()` for tables in this case is not the correct method. I was hoping to find out if there is a method to get or set the table link.

Comment: The above code simply links text of ALL cells in the table to stackoverflow.com. This is not what the OP has asked.

Comment: I would be pleased to suggest a simple and comprehensive solution to the question, but what if there is none? The asked question for its full solution requires a thorough study of the details, writing a bulk code. Perhaps a whole library ... Offer your answer if possible.